# Clickable cell in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can create clickable cells in pure js, but it doesn't work when trying to do something simple using angularjs: when clicking on the cell, it complained `dum` function doesn't exit.   Any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td onclick="dum();">{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    $scope.dum = function() { alert("hi you"); }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ng-click` will handle the link within angular, including translating it to the correct scope object.  `onclick` is the basic HTML feature, that isn't aware of angular or multiple scopes, and would only be able to find the function if it were declared globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript `onclick` event binding will work, but you do not have a function named `dum` in the global scope.

It would work if you were to do in your html, [for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8nm3uD?p=preview):

```
<script>
 function dum(){
   alert('test')
 }
</script>
```

In angular world you would need to use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead, so that the bound function expression is evaluated against the `scope`. `ng-click` is just a built-in directive that [binds click event internally](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62) and performs a digest cycle after evaluating the function expression bound to it. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdAylB?p=preview)